# Update apt cache from ansible when user is different from root

Tags: docker, ansible

I have the following Dockerfile I'm using to test my ansible playbook.

```
FROM ubuntu
ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git software-properties-common ansible 
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential curl
RUN apt-get install -y vim


RUN addgroup --gid 1000 gianluca
RUN adduser --gecos gianluca --uid 1000 --gid 1000 --disabled-password gianluca
USER gianluca
WORKDIR /home/gianluca

COPY . .
RUN make playbook
```

And this is the playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Update Apt
      become: true
      apt: update_cache=yes
      changed_when: False
```

Now, if I omit the creation of the USER in the Dockerfile, I can update the `apt` cache without issues.

However, once I introduce the creation of the USER gianluca in the Dockerfile, the playbook fails.

```
 > [10/10] RUN make playbook:
#0 0.386 ansible-playbook local.yml
#0 0.680 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
#0 0.682 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
#0 0.682 the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
#0 0.788
#0 0.788 PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************
#0 0.794
#0 0.794 TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
#0 1.350 ok: [localhost]
#0 1.358
#0 1.358 TASK [Update Apt] **************************************************************
#0 1.469 fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "/bin/sh: 1: sudo: not found\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 127}
#0 1.470
#0 1.470 PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
#0 1.470 localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
#0 1.470
#0 1.512 make: *** [makefile:25: playbook] Error 2
------
Dockerfile:16
--------------------
  14 |
  15 |     COPY . .
  16 | >>> RUN make playbook
  17 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c make playbook" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
make: *** [makefile:10: build] Error 1
```

Even after installing `sudo` — which I don't think is the best practice — I would have to provide a password.

```
 > [10/10] RUN make playbook:
#0 0.343 ansible-playbook local.yml
#0 0.619 [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
#0 0.622 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that
#0 0.622 the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
#0 0.725
#0 0.725 PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************
#0 0.732
#0 0.732 TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
#0 1.316 ok: [localhost]
#0 1.322
#0 1.322 TASK [Update Apt] **************************************************************
#0 1.442 fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
#0 1.443
#0 1.443 PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
#0 1.443 localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
#0 1.443
#0 1.488 make: *** [makefile:25: playbook] Error 2
------
Dockerfile:16
--------------------
  14 |
  15 |     COPY . .
  16 | >>> RUN make playbook
  17 |
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c make playbook" did not complete successfully: exit code: 2
make: *** [makefile:10: build] Error 1
```

What are people doing to get around this issue? Is there a way to become root to run `apt-get update` and then switch back to the user `gianluca` to complete the rest of the playbook? `become: true` should accomplish that, but it doesn't seem to work when the main user is something different from `root`. I would also like to do that without having to install `sudo` and provide a password.

Comment: I want to have a user other than root to simulate how this will work in real life. I will be calling ansible-playbook or ansible-pull from a user other than root. Specific tasks should be performed as root, but others don't. I also want the `$HOME` to be `/home/gianluca` instead of `/root`

Comment: In real life you usually don't run ansible playbooks targeting localhost from within a docker container. If this is just for tests, you need to think of your container as if it was rather a vm and install anything that is needed for ansible privilege escalation in that case (e.g. `sudo`) and run your task with `become: true`. Normal users are not allowed to update apt cache.